# Выполняется ли unboxing при использовании ссылочных типов и ArrayList?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, heap, unboxing

Есть фрагмент кода. В фрагменте кода создается объект класса Country country1 (ссылочный тип), далее создается    ArrayList. В ArrayList добавляем созданный объект country1 . После через явное приведение извлекаем объект country1  из созданного ArrayList.

Будет ли в данном случае происходить "boxing" и "unboxing"?

**C#:**

```
//Country это class
Country country1 = new Country { Name = "Kenya", Population = 25 };
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.Add(country1);
Country tmp = (Country)list1[0]; //Происходит ли тут unboxing?
```

Как я понимаю: так как работа происходит только со ссылочными типами, то распаковки и упаковки в данном случае не будет. Все объекты находятся в куче. Верны ли мои мысли?

Comment: Надеюсь, интерес чисто академический. С выходом `List<T>`, тип `ArrayList` считается устаревшим и не используется.

Answer (score 1):

вы правы, боксинга и анбоксинга тут нет